# I wanna hide id if NOT like but don't work SELECT * FROM character, character_actor WHERE character.id NOT LIKE character_actor.character_id;

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I wanna hide id if NOT like but don't work

> SELECT *
>       FROM character, character_actor WHERE character.id NOT LIKE character_actor.character_id;

```
id  name    id  character_id    actor_name
1   Doogie Howser   1   4       Alyson Hannigan
1   Doogie Howser   2   3       Alyson Hannigan
1   Doogie Howser   3   2       Neil Patrick Harris
2   Barney Stinson  1   4       Alyson Hannigan
2   Barney Stinson  2   3       Alyson Hannigan
2   Barney Stinson  4   1       Neil Patrick Harris
3   Lily Aldrin     1   4      Alyson Hannigan
3   Lily Aldrin     3   2    Neil Patrick Harris
3   Lily Aldrin     4   1    Neil Patrick Harris
4   Willow Rosenberg 2  3   Alyson Hannigan
4   Willow Rosenberg 3  2   Neil Patrick Harris
4   Willow Rosenberg 4  1   Neil Patrick Harris
```

Comment: `SELECT name, actor_name` maybe this is what you're trying to do ?

Comment: You can't hide the column for the particular row. May be you if not like you put the id as 0 using if condition

Comment: NO , for example id 1 to 10 and character_id  1  to 5 ,
I wanna hide all character_id  1 to 5 in ID if  form ID

Comment: Could you explain what you exactly want to get? Is it all characters who don't exist in character_actor?

Comment: You've tagged both Microsoft SQL Server and Oracle's open-source MySQL (not to mention mistakenly tagging both PHP and phpMyAdmin which are unrelated to the question), which database server are you using here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a NOT IN query:

```
SELECT *
FROM character WHERE character.id NOT IN (SELECT character_actor.character_id from character_actor)
```

It can also be accomplished with a NOT EXISTS.  Depending on the DBMS and structure, this might lead to better performance.

```
SELECT *
FROM character c WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL from character_actor ca WHERE ca.character_id=c.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT *
FROM character as c JOIN character_actor as ca
ON c.character_id != ca.character_id
```

Comment: share your both table structure.

Answer (score 0):

for example I have two tables , I wanna get two_table.name without one_table.name

```
one_table
id  name    
1   Dave    
2   Mary    
3   Fry male    
4   Leela   
5   Odie    

two_table
id  name    
1   Dave    
2   Mary    
3   Fry male    
4   Leela   
5   Odie    
6   Jumpy   
7   Sneakers
8   Jack
9   Malia
10  Lee
```